# Excel updating cell values in a range based on user changing another cell in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I've been working with some Excel VBA for a little while, but I'm still pretty new. I've searched the questions and found a few similar things but none that I've been able to correctly modify to my need.

I've got a data entry sheet where the user is manually entering data (from a validated list) in col B. If he selects N/A in col B, it needs to clear the associated data in col D and H (for the same row). The sheet has a fixed constant number of rows.

I've tried a couple of methods, but I'm pushing my limit of understanding here. The method below seems simple enough, but results in a crash of excel every time I try it. I've got it in the appropriate worksheet module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 500
        If Range("B" & i).Value = "N/A" Then
            Range("D" & i,"H" & i).Value = ""
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Can anyone clue me in as to where I'm fouling up?

Comment: You need to disable events prior to making a change to the worksheet, or else the `Worksheet_Change` event will fire, which will then make a change to the worksheet, which will cause the `Worksheet_Change` event to fire, which will then make a change to the worksheet ....

Comment: Thanks for the explanation YowE3K. That part makes a lot more sense now. I've actually hit that problem before and never knew why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should stop your memory overflowing:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    'check whether anything needs to be processed
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("B")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' stop other events from firing
        'process each cell that has changed
        For Each c In Intersect(Target, Columns("B")).Cells
            If c.Value = "N/A" Then
                c.Offset(0, 2).Value = ""
                c.Offset(0, 6).Value = ""
            End If
        Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' allow other events to fire
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Note: As A.S.H mentioned in their answer, if you are not actually checking for the string `N/A`, but are checking for a `#N/A` error condition, you will need to change your `If` statement.

Comment: Great, that worked with a couple small modifications. It was clearing the wrong cells, but after   playing with in for a couple minutes I found that offsets 0,1 and 0,5 worked. I think because some of the cells are merged?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> If Range("B" & i).Value = "N/A" Then
> ```

If the cell has `#N/A`, its `.Value` is neither a text nor a number, but an `Error Variant` with error code `2042`. You can't compare an error variant to a string, it's runtime error *type mismatch*.

So to check for an error case, use

```
If isError(Range("B" & i).Value) Then
```

Or to check for specific error `NA`, you can use

```
If Application.IsNA(Range("B" & i).Value) Then
```

Finally, if you want to get the displayed text of the cell whatever it's type, you can use the `.Text` property (not the recommended way to test it though):

```
 If Range("B" & i).Text = "#N/A" Then
```

Finally, after you correct this, as @YowE3k said in comment, disable events at the entry of your `Worksheet_Change` routine if you want to change things inside it, otherwise you will have a re-entrant routine and a guess what: `stackoverflow`.

Comment: I'm actually trying to evaluate for a user entered text string of "N/A". However, the info about #N/A is useful as I've seen error that pop up a few times. Thanks